# Apple iPhone calendar

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5C dumped information already set from calendar and won't save new events to the calendar. I am able to enter the event information but when I tap on "add" the information is not saved to that calendar date.

it was working fine then all of a sudden pre-entered events are missing and new events are not saved when "add" is tapped.

Comment: Do you have any syncing accounts such as iCloud or Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with your default iPhone calendar account. How many calendars do you have on your iPhone? I'd suggest that you go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars and under the "Calendars" section, see what calendar account exactly is set as Default.

The account set as default will be the place where all newly-created events will be saved to.